# Как составить функцию расстояния между кривыми?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Нужно найти наименьшее расстояние между двумя кривыми методом градиентного спуска: 
x^2+y^2−2*x+4*y+3 = 0 и x = (cosϕ)^3 − 1, y = 2 + (sinϕ)^3

Суть вопроса в том, что я не могу составить функцию расстояния между точками на этих прямых, чтобы потом её минимизировать. Подскажете, как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, да, мне нужно найти такие точки, одну на одной кривой, другую на второй, расстояния между которыми будет минимально. Я знаю формулу расстояния между двумя точками: sqrt((x2-x1)**2 - (y2-y1)**2), проблема в том, чтобы из данных уравнений кривых составить такое уравнение

Comment: Ну например можно первое уравнение перевести в параметрическую форму от параметра `t`. (Второе у вас и так уже параметрическое от параметра `ϕ`), Тогда вы сможете составить функцию расстояния от двух параметров `D(t, ϕ)`. А далее уже устраивать градиентный спуск по этим двум параметрам. Первое уравнение - это на самом деле окружность.

Comment: Только учтите, что там картинка хитрая, и есть не один минимум, так что не скатитесь в локальный минимум, который никак не будет кратчайшим расстоянием...

Comment: @Harry, для того чтобы иметь возможность скатиться в локальный минимум сначала надо суметь описать функцию расстояния между точками двух кривых - я так понял в этом и состоит суть вопроса...

Comment: @MaxU По-моему, AnT полностью ответил на вопрос... Я интереса для эту задачку решил - потому и говорю о подводных камнях...

Comment: @AnT, вы можете оформить это как ответ? Похоже у меня ступор - не вижу как первое уравнение перевести в параметрическую форму от параметра `t` и как в итогу будет выглядеть функция `D(t, ϕ)`? Это в полярных координатах??

Comment: @Harry, подожду полноценного ответа... Мне очень стыдно, но комментария от AnT лично мне недостаточно для решения...

Comment: Harry, почему бы вам не опубликовать решение ? ;) PS надеюсь @AnT тоже опубликует свое решение...

Comment: @MaxU Потому что я решал в Wolfram Mathematica...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое уравнение в параметрических координатах -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*t* меняется от 0 до 2*pi, как и параметр во втором уравнении.

Дальше все просто - целевая функция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А выглядит она вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сами кривые:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете добавить небольшое пояснение как вы получили целевую функцию?

Comment: По теореме Пифагора :) - квадрат расстояния от точки, соответствующей значению *t* для первой кривой, и значению *u* для второй.